# Are all sites a subsite of the root site in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to retrieve all SharePoint Sites via the [Microsoft Graph REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Looking at the [Site resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0), I can see there are methods to get a root site, to get subsites, but also, to get sites by group.

Are all SharePoint sites, including group sites able to be found as subsites of the root site? Or do I need to retrieve every group and enumerate those too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To retrieve *all the sites* across tenant [`Search for sites` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) could be utilized, for example:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

To retrieve *only* [group sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#access-a-group-team-site) indeed, it appears the only supported approach would be to:

- list all the groups, for example: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')&$select=id`
- and enumerate every group to retrieve group site:  `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/sites/root`

Answer (score 1):

No. The organization root is a sibling to group sites.

The API does have a basic search capability, if that helps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-search?view=graph-rest-1.0